# How to make Muntha chart using vedic astrology?

Tags: astrology

I have seen that some websites ( like astrosage.com) creates muntha chart and then calculate the varshfal *aka* "Yearly Predictions". I've found them to be quite accurate.

I would like to learn to create a muntha chart.Can someone explain how do we create a muntha chart using vedic astrology?

Comment: I have limited understanding on this topic. Although, Varshafala is a considered a branch in itself in Jyotisha, hence might be too broad to discuss here. Also, you might want to skim through this book by Bepin Behari Das: https://books.google.co.in/books?isbn=8120818873

Comment: Also, you could ask the question on this forum: http://lightonvedicastrology.com/phpBB3_0/index.php

Comment: @AmitSaxena I don't think Varshaphala is a branch in Jyotisha(If I am wrong then please correct me), I can assert that it is just a broad view and calculated according to the Big(Major Shifts in positions) motion of planets not the basic Chandra Movement which is of 2(1/2) days for each rashi. Quoting from Wikipedia "(Muntha chart)enables the astrologer to forecast events of immediate importance" whereas daily calculations are made on the basis of Moon Movement, and even a slightest movement in sky is noted. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Muntha_%28astrology%29

Comment: @Yogi: I think a better word than branch would be a technique or a methodology used in Jyotish :)

Answer (score 1):

This is a type of Astrology which is not of Indian origin but came to India via Persian influence. The principle is "Varsha Phala" or "yearly chart".

This is very useful because unlike the lagna chart, it helps in brief reading for one year period.

The chart is cast during the time when one enters a new year from his birth when the sun is in exactly same degrees of his birth chart. A chart is made during this time is known as [Varsha](http://www.vedic-astrology.net/Courses/Tajika-Courses.asp) Phala kundali.

Muntha is an important part of the Kundali. It changes one sign every year in a fixed manner. It is NOT  planet but a progressive lagna (ascendant) which changes one house every year. So it is not actually muntha chart but year chart of which muntha is a part.

Comment: Allright! but how do i make my year chart?

Comment: and from the year chart,how to calculate muntha?

Comment: @kashish at the time of birth , the first varsha pravesha chart, muntha will be in the ascendant of the chart. it will progress one house every year.. hence at the age of 12, the muntha will be in the 12th house and so on. for related discussions you can join agama chat room.

Comment: @RakeshJoshi Please add this comment in the answer too. It's helpful for readers.